# Store data for dif . language

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I'm planning quiz app in several languages. Pictures will be same for all languages, but questions, answers and add. Information will be different. It can be 300 - 500 sentences for every language.

Should I use string res in dif directories for dif languages or maybe better way exists? SQL or something?

Comment: If there are total 500-1000 sentences in each language, that will not be any issue with `strings.xml` for each language.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with a string.xml file in your resources folder. Create different folders for each language (values-en, values-es, etc) and inside these folders add the strings.xml file with your text resources.  Use the same tags in all files and store a different value for each language. Then populate your views with the corresponding xml as you please

example:
 \res\values-en\strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="greeting">Hello</string>
</resources>
```

\res\values-es\strings.xml:

```
<resources>
        <string name="greeting">Hola</string>
    </resources>
```

and this is how you change the language 'locale' programmatically:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

make sure in your manifest you include the following under your activity:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

([source](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages))

Comment: Thanks, I understand it, but is it ok if so much information are in string resources? Or maybe better use sqllite?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having big xml files for strings. Why add a database and classes to handle the communication with it, if you can simply use what's native to android?